# If I call ShellExecuteEx, why does GetExitCodeProcess say the program terminated even though it's still running?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, shellexecute

I want to open a file which is initially saved to SQL table, but is saved to disk before the call to ShellExecuteEx. Once it is saved I now have a valid file path and theoretically should be able to use this function to accomplish my goal. I need the program to open the file in its appropriate program and wait until that program closes before continuing. Currently the code will launch the correct application and open the passed file, but it does this without waiting (which I know because I display a message to indicate when the application terminates) and the app I wrote which is supposed to launch the correct program closes. It displays the message, then launches the program. I will admit that I do not fully understand how ShellExecuteEx works and have used code I found on the web in conjunction with my code to achieve the desired result. Below you will find the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
procedure Fire(FileStr: String);
var
  SEInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;
  ExitCode: DWORD;
  ExecuteFile, ParamString, StartInString: string;
begin
  ExecuteFile:= FileStr;
  FillChar(SEInfo, SizeOf(SEInfo), 0) ;
  SEInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(TShellExecuteInfo);
  with SEInfo do 
  begin
    fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    Wnd := Application.Handle;
    lpFile := PChar(ExecuteFile) ;
    nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
  end;

  if ShellExecuteEx(@SEInfo) then
  begin
    repeat
      Application.ProcessMessages;
      GetExitCodeProcess(SEInfo.hProcess, ExitCode) ;
    until (ExitCode <> STILL_ACTIVE) or Application.Terminated;
    ShowMessage('App terminated') ;
  end
    else ShowMessage('Error starting App') ;
end;
```

I realized that the the file I was writing to disk hadn't finished which is why the message appeared before the program. Adding another application.Processmessages after the call to write the file to disk resolved this. GetExitCodeProcess still does not return the value of STILL_ACTIVE while the called app is open, though.

After doing more research I have decided to open a new question that is more pointed at what I am trying to accomplish. If anyone is interested in following it, you can find it here

[How do I wait to delete a file until after the program I started has finished using it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734258/what-is-the-best-way-to-execute-an-external-app-via-delphi)

Comment: `Application.Terminated` refers to your application, not the one that you ShellExecute()d. By intention?

Comment: No. It wasn't my intention. Although it makes perfect sense what you said. Why does it return true then when the program is still running? It would be fine if it stopped waiting once my program shutdown. Application.Terminated is set to true directly after the call to Application.ProcessMessages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it stands, there's not enough information in the question to give you an answer that explains exactly what is happening in your scenario. You have not done enough debugging yet. So this answer will be of a more didactic nature. I'm going to attempt to teach you how to diagnose a problem of this nature.

First of all, let's clear up the obvious problems with your code, that are important but peripheral to the actual problem.

- You are running a busy wait loop. That's always a bad idea. You are burning 100% CPU in the main GUI thread just waiting. There are two obvious ways to avoid that. Use a thread to perform the call to `ShellExecuteEx` and the subsequent wait, as suggested by Marko. Or use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` to perform a wait that can be interrupted in order to process input events.
- If `ShellExecuteEx` does return a process handle to you, you leak it. When an API function returns a handle, you typically are responsible for closing it when you are done with it. That takes a call to `CloseHandle`. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759784.aspx) calls this out: *The calling application is responsible for closing the handle when it is no longer needed.*
- You are not performing comprehensive error checking. You call a Win32 API function and fail to check its return value for an error. More on this later, but it's critical that you perform correct error checking.

Now, let's look closely at the problem you report in the question. The problem is that the call to `ShellExecuteEx` succeeds, the document is opened, but the busy wait returns before the process that displays the document closes. Your busy loop looks like this:

```
repeat
  Application.ProcessMessages;
  GetExitCodeProcess(SEInfo.hProcess, ExitCode);
until (ExitCode <> STILL_ACTIVE) or Application.Terminated;
```

There's really not a lot of code here. If this loop returns earlier than you expect, how can that happen? The loop terminates when `ExitCode <> STILL_ACTIVE` or when `Application.Terminated` is `True`. The first thing to do is to isolate which of those conditions leads to termination of the loop. Some straightforward debugging would yield that information. I find it hard to believe that you accidentally terminated your application so I am going to proceed on the basis that `Application.Terminated` is `False` and the `ExitCode` test terminates the loop.

So, let's look again at the call to `GetExitCodeProcess`. This is immediately suspicious to me because you don't perform any error checking. Now, I happen to have extra information that you are perhaps lacking. Specifically that `SEInfo.hProcess` may not contain a process handle. That makes it easier for me to anticipate the problems, but you can learn all this under the debugger. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759784.aspx) again:

> A handle to the newly started application. This member is set on
>   return and is always NULL unless fMask is set to
>   SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS. Even if fMask is set to
>   SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS, hProcess will be NULL if no process was
>   launched. For example, if a document to be launched is a URL and an
>   instance of Internet Explorer is already running, it will display the
>   document. No new process is launched, and hProcess will be NULL.
>
> **Note**  ShellExecuteEx does not always return an hProcess, even if a process is launched as the result of the call. For example, an
>   hProcess does not return when you use SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST to invoke
>   IContextMenu.

So, perhaps what is happening is that your document is being processed by the shell in a way such that the value of `hProcess` returned to you is `NULL`, i.e. `0`. When that happens, the call to `GetExitCodeProcess` fails and returns `False`. That's the error condition that you did not check. You simply called `GetExitCodeProcess` and ignored whether or not it succeeded. If that call did not succeed, then `ExitCode` will not have been assigned a meaningful value and it is simply a mistake to attempt to read `ExitCode` at all. It only has meaning when `GetExitCodeProcess` returns `True`.

There's yet another failure mode that is even more subtle. It's possible that the call to `ShellExecuteEx` returns a valid process handle. But the process that is started deals with the request by passing it on to a different process and then terminating. From your perspective the process that displays the document is still running, but the process that `ShellExecuteEx` gives you has terminated. This commonly happens when an instance the process that displays the document is already running. For example, try calling your `Fire` function passing a `.pas` file when your Delphi IDE is open. A new process is started, but it immediately hands the file off to the running Delphi IDE and terminates.

OK, that's all I can think of for now. I hope that this helps you track down what's really happening in your scenario. It may not be the news you wish to hear though because I suspect that you will find that the approach of using `ShellExecuteEx` and waiting on the process handle that it returns will not meet your needs. Unfortunately opening a document using the shell is much more complicated than it might initially seem.

Comment: David, I appreciate you taking the time to try and help. I agree I did not do a lot of initial debugging because I was getting lost and didn't understand what was happening. I posted on here to try and narrow down what might be causing my issues. I am new to some of these concepts and sometimes it helps to get the opinions of more seasoned programmers like yourself. I looked into the documentation before I even posted here but felt like I didn't get it. Which again is why I came here. Your detailed description should help me understand the mechanics a little better, and I thank you.

Comment: Please don't take what I said in a negative way. I was trying to offer some insight into how to debug this sort of problem yourself to hopefully help you in the future. As well as that, I hope that I will have described the cause of the actual problem, somewhere in the answer.

Comment: I understand and again thank you. I didn't know how to go about looking into this and you definitely gave me some avenues to explore. I've already figured out what was causing the application to close, so right there, that's progress.

Answer (score 0):

Your `repeat..until` loop is wrong here. Avoid using `Application.ProcessMessages()` to make your application not block because it's bad practice and can/will cause unforeseen problems and weird bugs.

Instead, use thread to wait for app termination:

```
unit uSEWaitThread;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, System.Classes;

type
  TSEWaitThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FFile     : String;
    FSESuccess: Boolean;
    FExitCode : DWORD;
    FParentWnd: HWND;

  protected
    procedure Execute; override;

  public
    constructor Create(const AFile: String; const AParentWindowHandle: HWND; const AOnDone: TNotifyEvent);

    property ExitCode           : DWORD read FExitCode;
    property ShellExecuteSuccess: Boolean read FSESuccess;
  end;

implementation

uses
  Winapi.ShellApi;


constructor TSEWaitThread.Create(const AFile: String; const AParentWindowHandle: HWND; const AOnDone: TNotifyEvent);
begin
  FreeOnTerminate := TRUE;

  FFile := AFile;
  FParentWND := AParentWindowHandle;
  FSESuccess := FALSE;
  FExitCode := 0;
  OnTerminate := AOnDone;

  inherited Create;
end;

procedure TSEWaitThread.Execute;
var
  exec_info: TShellExecuteInfo;
begin
  FillChar(exec_info, SizeOf(TShellExecuteInfo), 0);
  exec_info.cbSize := SizeOf(TShellExecuteInfo);
  exec_info.fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS or SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI;
  exec_info.Wnd := FParentWnd;
  exec_info.lpFile := PChar(FFile);
  exec_info.nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;

  if ShellExecuteEx(@exec_info) then
  begin
    FSESuccess := TRUE;
    WaitForSingleObject(exec_info.hProcess, INFINITE);
    GetExitCodeProcess(exec_info.hProcess, FExitCode);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Following line will launch thread:

```
TSEWaitThread.Create('C:\test.txt', Handle, SEWaitThreadDone);
```

And sample of callback function that would process thread result:

```
procedure TForm1.SEWaitThreadDone(Sender: TObject);
var
  se_wait_thread: TSEWaitThread;
begin
  se_wait_thread := Sender as TSEWaitThread;

  if se_wait_thread.ShellExecuteSuccess then
  begin
    ShowMessage(Format('App exit code: %d', [se_wait_thread.ExitCode]));
  end
  else
    ShowMessage('Error Starting App');
end;
```

Comment: Why the sleep(50)? Have you had a look at the CPU load? Why don't you just WaitForSingleObject() on the hProcess handle, maybe with a larger timeout if you really think you need one?

Comment: @Marko My problem is now Exit code is not returning the Value of STILL_ACTIVE. and your code still seems to rely on Exit Code being not equal to STILL_ACTIVE. Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

Comment: @JensG, you're correct, I edited code above. I also removed unnecessary `OnDone()` callback, since `OnTerminate()` already implements this.

Comment: @CodeMonkey if app closed with success, `ExitCode` should be `0`. Alternatively, you can use `WaitForSingleObject(exec_info.hProcess, INFINITE)` and remove `repeat..until` loop completely, if you really only need to wait for app to terminate, and don't need process exit code.

Comment: I'd still use a larger timeout. 50 msec is too low. You could avoid the timeout completely by means of an `TEvent` which is `Set()` from the ouside when the thread should be forced to terminate, but at the (moderate) cost of an additional kernel object. Then you could `WaitForMultipleObjects(2, @handles, FALSE, INFINITE)`. If you don't need to call `Terminated` inside the thread, then use Marko's way.

Comment: Actually, would `WaitForSingleObject(exec_info.hProcess, INFINITE); GetExitCodeProcess(exec_info.hProcess, FExitCode)` work? I believe it will. I updated the answer.

Comment: By the way, what do you get back, if it is not `STILL_ACTIVE`? If it is zero, then you should consider calling `GetLastError()`.

Comment: I will give it a shot....It's weird now that I use Application.ProcessMessages after my code to write the file to the desktop I am getting the correct exit code, but I don't understand what is setting Application.Terminated to true. If I can figure that out than I should be all good. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not opposed to using threads. I haven't worked with them yet, and will admit to a novice level of understanding them. I just want to understand why when I use Application.ProcessMessages it sets Application.Terminated to true.....  it might be pointing to another problem altogether.

Comment: By the way I just wanted to thank both of you for all your help and Input.

Comment: @CodeMonkey Read this: [The Dark Side of Application.ProcessMessages in Delphi Applications](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/delphi-processmessages-dark-side.htm)

Comment: May I know why I got -1 on answer that seems perfectly valid to me? Are there better ways to do this other than running it in thread?

Comment: To be honest, I have never checked `Application.Terminated` and I  think I'll very likely never do it. To answer your question: `Application.Terminated` is set in `TApplication.ProcessMessage()` when a `WM_QUIT` message is received. Why that happens in your code - I don't know. But if I were you I would set a breakpoint there and look what happens.

Comment: I downvoted because you don't address the question. You instead discuss ProcessMessages and threading. If the code in the question fails, so will the code in this answer. Also, you still leak a process handle and the code is somewhat sloppy.